# Conceptual problem in pushing an object in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays named "products" and "admin". In the AddInfo function, I use s & j equal to products and admin respectively. Now, in the `console.log` statements above push statement, the length of the array in the console is equal and after the push statement also it is equal even though the push statement of products has been commented out.

On uncommenting the push statement for s (i.e. this.state.products) the product shows 2 times on the screen, however, it is only added once in the database and on refreshing one of the copies gets removed automatically which is weird.

```
AddInfo(info){

  let s = this.state.products;
  let j = this.state.admin;

  let obj ={name:info.productName};

  axios.post('http://localhost:5000/admin',obj).then((res)=>{

    if (info.productName !== "") {

      console.log(this.state.products);
      console.log(this.state.admin);

      // s.push(res.data);
      j.push(res.data);

      console.log(this.state.products);
      console.log(this.state.admin);

      this.setState({
        products:s,
        admin:j
      })

    } else {
      alert("Please fill all the fields.")
    }

    console.log("Products",this.state.products,res.data);

  });

};
```

Comment: _"after the push statement also it is equal even though the push statement of products has been commented out."_ - Then `this.state.products === this.state.admin`

Comment: You are making a copy of `products` and `admin` in `s` and `j` respectively. But after pushing you are again printing actual state and **NOT** a copied one so you are getting same value (But the value is added in copied array). You should print copied array after pushing and check you are getting correct values.

Comment: The object in being added to both the state arrays. What i meant was that the variable s is is not being used and an object is still added to it. Eg. in the first 2 console.log statements, the length of both these array is 0. On adding an object, the length becomes 1 for both of these which is weird because I didn't even push the object.Nevermind though, commenting the s.push statement has fixed everything for me

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the state the wrong way.. you should set the state in a callback function.

```
const newProduct ={...};
this.setstate(st => ({
    products: [...st, newProduct]
}));
```

Comment: But why is everything working fine when I comment the push statement of s (i.e. this.state.products)

Answer (score 0):

#### Never change the state directly, use `setState` instead.

By doing `j.push(res.data);` you're basically doing `this.state.admin.push(res.data)` because of the way variable assignment works on Javascript.

So you are mutating the state, which you should **never do** directly because pushing a new item on the this.state.admin array does not replace the underlying array.

A good read: https://medium.com/pro-react/a-brief-talk-about-immutability-and-react-s-helpers-70919ab8ae7c

Comment: Isn't j a copy of this.state.admin, updating which, shouldn't have any effect on the state? If doing j.push changes the states or mutates the state as you say, then there should be no use of setState here,right?